# IBM QE - Parameters that differentiate the various backends

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I'm doing a university thesis using IBM's quantum backends. In my analysis I am making some considerations on what differentiates one backend from another other than the **number of qubits** and **quantum volume**.

The parameters that come into play are:

- **Frequency**: the difference in energy between the ground and exicted states
- **Readout Error**: the error in measuring qubit
- **T1**: the relaxation time
- **T2**: the coherence time
- **CNOT error**: the error on operating the 2-qubit gate
- **Sqrt-x (sx) error**: ?
- **Anharmonicity**: ?
- **Gate time**: ?

The last three I have not yet understood.

Is each single qubit powered individually or does it follow the topological configuration of the backend?

For example if I used a 5 qubit system and used the linear configuration 0-1-2-3-4 and used 0-1 and 3-4. Does the current have to go from 2 to get to 3-4? Or are they powered individually?

I tried to look for articles and information on the internet that gave me these answers but I did not find anything, if you have any material that may be useful to me, please link it to me!

Comment: Just note that T2 is dephasing time (i.e. a time during it a quantum phase does not change). T1 and T2 are together considered as parameters describing decoherence.

Comment: Hi Marco, could you tell me exactly what you mean by "powered qubit" and what "individually powered" means? I have never seen this expression, I'm curious

Comment: @Lena I mean if the current passes through certain qubits according to the topology or if a current generator is connected to each qubit